# Row above List Object Table that includes Tables Name with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that currently creates 2 tables across 2 sheets.  One table works fine, that is located on the Instructions page.  The other table is dynamically created on another sheet, it also works fine.  However I want this table to have a row above it with the name of the table in it.  So end result, table is generated when macro is ran with the name of the Table above the table.

The macro currently asks the user to name the Table (Supply Chain), which is updated as the actual table name in the Name Manager.  That is the varible (Y) that I want to be in the row above the generated table in the Dynamic Table section of this code.

```
Sub GenerateSupplyChain2()

    Worksheets("JP8").Columns("D").ClearContents
    Worksheets("JP8").Range("D6:D300").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[+1],S1CODE,2,0)"
     
    Worksheets("JP5").Columns("D").ClearContents
    Worksheets("JP5").Range("D6:D300").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[+1],S2CODE,2,0)"
     
    Worksheets("F76").Columns("D").ClearContents
    Worksheets("F76").Range("D6:D300").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[+1],S3CODE,2,0)"
     
    Worksheets("JA1").Columns("D").ClearContents
    Worksheets("JA1").Range("D6:D300").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[+1],S4CODE,2,0)"
     
    Worksheets("JAA").Columns("D").ClearContents
    Worksheets("JAA").Range("D6:D300").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[+1],S5CODE,2,0)"
    
    Dim Y As Variant
Y = InputBox("Name your Supply Chain")

    Dim counterSheet As Worksheet
    Set counterSheet = Sheets("CounterSheet")
    
    Dim lastColumn As Long
    lastColumn = counterSheet.Cells(2, counterSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    If lastColumn = 1 And IsEmpty(counterSheet.Cells(2, 1).Value) Then
        counterSheet.Cells(2, 1).Value = 1
    Else
        counterSheet.Cells(2, lastColumn + 1).Value = counterSheet.Cells(2, lastColumn).Value + 1
    End If
    
    Dim Z As Long
    Z = counterSheet.Cells(2, lastColumn).Value

''instructions page
Const COL_CNT = 4 ' cols count of the table (ListObject)
Const COL_KEY = "AA" ' used to determine the last row
Const FIRST_ROW = 5
Dim i As Variant
i = InputBox("How many DFSP's in this Supply Chain?", "Enter Quantity")
If Not IsNumeric(i) Then
        MsgBox "Please input a number.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
End If
If i < 1 Then Exit Sub
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Set sht = Worksheets("Instructions")
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, COL_KEY).End(xlUp).Row
With sht.Cells(LastRow, COL_KEY)
    If Len(.Value) > 0 Or (Not .ListObject Is Nothing) Then
        LastRow = LastRow + 1
    End If
    If LastRow < FIRST_ROW Then LastRow = 5
End With
Dim tabRng As Range
Set tabRng = sht.Cells(LastRow, COL_KEY).Resize(i + 1, COL_CNT)
Dim objTable As ListObject
Set objTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, tabRng, , xlYes)
objTable.HeaderRowRange.Value = Array("Numeric", "Name", "Alpha", "Location") ' for testing
objTable.TableStyle = "TableStyleLight1"

    objTable.DataBodyRange.Columns(1).Value = Z
    objTable.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 3).formula = _
    "=D5"
    objTable.DataBodyRange.Columns(2).Value = Y

'dynamic page

Dim MySheet As String, ws As Worksheet
MySheet = Sheets("Instructions").Range("AF1").Value
Set ws = Sheets(MySheet)
    
    Const COL_KEY1 = "E" ' used to determine the last row
    Const FIRST_ROW1 = 6
    Const HEADER_RNG = "D2:AZ2" ' source of header
    Const BASE_SHT = "Base Data"
    
    Dim oSht As Worksheet, LastRow1 As Long
    Set oSht = Sheets(MySheet)
    LastRow1 = oSht.Cells(oSht.Rows.Count, COL_KEY1).End(xlUp).Row
    With oSht.Cells(LastRow1, COL_KEY1)
        If Len(.Value) > 0 Or (Not .ListObject Is Nothing) Then
            LastRow1 = LastRow1 + 3
        End If
        If LastRow1 < FIRST_ROW1 Then LastRow1 = FIRST_ROW1
    End With
    Dim tabRng1 As Range, headerRng As Range, objTable1 As ListObject
    Set headerRng = Sheets("BASE Data").Range(HEADER_RNG)
    Set tabRng1 = oSht.Cells(LastRow1, COL_KEY1).Resize(i + 1, headerRng.Columns.Count)
    Set objTable1 = Worksheets(MySheet).ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, tabRng1, , xlYes)
    
    objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Value = headerRng.Value
    objTable1.ShowTotals = True
    objTable1.TableStyle = "TableStyleLight1"
    objTable1.TotalsRowRange.Cells.Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
    objTable1.TotalsRowRange.Cells.Font.Bold = True
    objTable1.TotalsRowRange.Cells.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    objTable1.TotalsRowRange.Cells.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Cells.Interior.Color = RGB(166, 166, 166)
    
    
With objTable1.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange
    .Value = objTable1.Parent.Range("CB5").Resize(.Rows.Count).Value
End With
    
    objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 2).formula = _
        "=INDIRECT(""RC[-2]"",0)"
        
        objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 3).formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 2).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!E:AS,2,FALSE)"
    
        objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 4).formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 2).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!E:AS,3,FALSE)"
    
        objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 5).formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 2).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!E:AS,4,FALSE)"
    
        objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 6).formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 2).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!E:AS,5,FALSE)"
    
        objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 7).formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 2).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!E:AS,6,FALSE)"
    
        objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 8).formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 2).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!E:AS,7,FALSE)"
    
        objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 9).formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 2).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!E:AS,8,FALSE)"
    
        objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 10).formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 2).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!E:AS,9,FALSE)"
    
        objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 11).formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 2).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!E:AS,10,FALSE)"
    
        objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 12).formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 2).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!E:AS,11,FALSE)"
    
        objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 13).formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 2).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!E:AS,12,FALSE)"
    
        objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 14).formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 2).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!E:AS,13,FALSE)"
    
        objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 15).formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 2).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!E:AS,14,FALSE)"
    
        objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 16).formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 2).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!E:AS,15,FALSE)"
    
        objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 17).formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 2).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!E:AS,16,FALSE)"
    
        objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 18).formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 2).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!E:AS,17,FALSE)"
    
        objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 19).formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 2).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!E:AS,18,FALSE)"
    
        objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 20).formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 2).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!E:AS,19,FALSE)"
    
        objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 21).formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 2).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!E:AS,20,FALSE)"
    
        objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 22).formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 2).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!E:AS,21,FALSE)"
    
        objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 23).formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 2).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!E:AS,22,FALSE)"
    
         objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 24).formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 2).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!E:AS,23,FALSE)"
    
         objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 25).formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 2).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!E:AS,24,FALSE)"
    
         objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 26).formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 2).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!E:AS,25,FALSE)"
    
         objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 27).formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 2).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!E:AS,26,FALSE)"
    
         objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 28).formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 2).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!E:AS,27,FALSE)"
    
         objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 29).formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 2).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!E:AS,28,FALSE)"
    
         objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 30).formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 2).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!E:AS,29,FALSE)"
    
         objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 31).formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 2).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!E:AS,30,FALSE)"
    
         objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 32).formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 2).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!E:AS,31,FALSE)"
    
         objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 33).formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 2).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!E:AS,32,FALSE)"
    
         objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 34).formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 2).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!E:AS,33,FALSE)"
    
         objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 35).formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 2).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!E:AS,34,FALSE)"
    
         objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 36).formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 2).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!E:AS,35,FALSE)"
    
         objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 37).formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 2).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!E:AS,36,FALSE)"
    
         objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 38).formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 2).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!E:AS,37,FALSE)"
    
         objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 39).formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 2).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!E:AS,38,FALSE)"
    
         objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 40).formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 2).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!E:AS,39,FALSE)"
    
         objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 41).formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 2).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!E:AS,40,FALSE)"
    
         objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 42).formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 2).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!E:AS,41,FALSE)"
    
         objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 43).formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 2).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!E:AS,42,FALSE)"
    
    
     objTable1.Name = Y
     
     Sheets(MySheet).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
     Sheets(MySheet).VerticallAlignment = xlCenter
     Sheets(MySheet).WrapText = True
     Sheets(MySheet).Range("D5:AZ1000").Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
     


    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Changed lines are marked with `**`

```vb
    With sht.Cells(LastRow, COL_KEY)
        If Len(.Value) > 0 Or (Not .ListObject Is Nothing) Then
            LastRow = LastRow + 1
        End If
        If LastRow < FIRST_ROW Then LastRow = 5
    End With
    sht.Cells(LastRow, COL_KEY) = Y ' **
    Dim tabRng As Range
    Set tabRng = sht.Cells(LastRow + 1, COL_KEY).Resize(i + 1, COL_CNT) ' **
```

---

btw, the code to apply `VLOOKUP` formula can be simplified with a `For` loop.

```vb
    Dim j As Long, sFormula As String, dataRng As Range
    Set dataRng = objTable1.DataBodyRange
    sFormula = "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objTable1.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 2).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!E:AS,^%^,FALSE)"
    For i = 2 To 42
        dataRng.Cells(1, i + 1).Formula = Replace(sFormula, "^%^", CStr(i))
    Next j
```